# How is this construct (int) { 1 } called?

Tags: c

How is the construct `(int) { 1 }` called in C? A guess was "anonymous constant", but this didn't show any helpful on Google. As a sidenote, you can use this construct to tell ioctl that you want to use a variable with the value of 1: `ioctl (..., &(int) { 1 })`.

Comment: Note that `int` is the wrong type for `{1}`. It is supposed to be `(int[]){1}`.

Comment: @jørgensen: no, this is valid. The type is determined by the parenthesized part and may be a simple type such as `int`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's called a "[compound literal](http://drdobbs.com/184401404)" and constructs a temporary `int`-typed lvalue.

Comment: Note also that compound literals are lvalues which when passed via a pointer, as is done here, can be changed.  In the above call the temp value might be modified by ioctl() which might potentially be a hard-to-find bug.